# Modifying <string name="myname">myvalue</string> XML elements in PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom

I'm trying to programatically modify some XML elements using PHP.  They have the form

```
<string name="myname1">myvalue1</string>
<string name="myname2">myvalue2</string>
```

etc.  I do not have control over the incoming structure of this XML file.  Is there a good way to edit these in PHP?  I've tried using a DOMDocument, but I'm not having much luck making it work because the elements don't have IDs specified and doing a search by tag name gives me all the strings, not the one I want.  Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: You'll need to give us more than that. How does the XML structure look like? What are you trying to extract from it?

Comment: The XML is basically a list of these string elements.  I am trying to modify the values myvalue1 and myvalue2 programatically given that I know the myname1 and myname2 I am looking for.

Comment: Yes, I know the names of the elements I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOMXPath solves this problem nicely:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($input);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$string = $xpath->query("//string[@name='myname1']")->item(0);
if( $string) {
    // do something
}
```